# PostgreSQL - "Fatal: could not access file"

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally ran

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET session_preload_libraries = ''; -- empty string
```

and now I can't log in to my PostgreSQL (v.14) database. I'm getting

> [58P01] FATAL: could not access file "": No such file or directory

Is there any way to fix this? I can't execute any command because of this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect to some other database, like 'postgres' or 'template1', and reset the parameter.

If there are no other databases you can connect to, then you might need to restart the cluster in `--single` mode to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The offending setting should be in a postgresql.auto.conf file of your cluster's data directory. Edit that file and restart the cluster to fix the problem.

Comment: Please explain what setting?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).